# CakePHP pretty URL redirect

Tags: php, cakephp, pretty-urls

Due to my hosting company's policies I am using pretty url in CakePHP (without the Apache mod rewrite). My homepage is at:

http://stthomasedu.org/index.php/home

How can I redirect traffic from

'http://stthomasedu.org/' to 'http://stthomasedu.org/index.php/home' ?

I've tried to edit index.php with

```
header("Location:http://stthomasedu.org/index.php/home");
```

but it's not working, every time I have to manually enter the URL "http://stthomasedu.org/index.php/home"

Any ideas?

SOLVED : IN C-PANEL I HAVE AN OPTION TO REDIRECT ALL MY TRAFFIC TO (http://stthomasedu.org) ANY LOCATION (now i set it to http://stthomasedu.org/index.php/home)

Comment: Maybe it's better to set it in your webserver configuration. Which one are you using? (apache, nginx, lighttpd, ..)

Comment: @j0k apache , its in shared hosting

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Apache, you can add [these lines](http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/redirect-domain-to-file/) in a `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stthomasedu.org$
RewriteRule ^$ http://stthomasedu.org/index.php/home [L,R=301]
```

Comment: i am using cakephp's pretty url i which .htaccess files forbidden

Comment: i mean , while using cake php's pretty url , we should delete .htaccess files.

Comment: and if you re-add it just with these lines, "pretty url" won't be affected I suppose.

Comment: I guess you should delete the htaccess because cake php use special rule inside that can break pretty-url. If you re-add the htaccess file with only lines I gave you, I don't think it will interact with cake php and then break pretty-url. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to exit after your header() call?

```
header('Location: /index.php/home');
exit;
```